# Package for testing network connection

Tags: python, python-2.x, networking

I wrote this package for monitoring the state of a network connection in the terminal because my net connection would go down for a few minutes at a time and come back up. I think it could be used in other applications.

I'm looking for any advice on how to improve or extend this package in any way possible.

[Package repo](https://github.com/Ricky-Wilson/netstatus)

My concerns are as follows:

1. Is the package "Pythonic"?
2. Does the package contain any obvious bugs/errors/flaws?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


'''
This module is for checking a networks status.
'''

import socket
from time import sleep as _sleep
from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import signal

TIMEOUT = 2

class NetworkStatus(object):
    def timeout(seconds=1, error_message=os.strerror(errno.ETIME)):
        def decorator(func):
            def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
                return
                signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
                signal.alarm(seconds)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    signal.alarm(0)
                return result

            return wraps(func)(wrapper)

        return decorator


    def set_timeout(self, t_out):
        '''
        Update the global variable TIMEOUT.
        '''
        global TIMEOUT
        TIMEOUT = t_out

    def sleep(self,delay):
        '''
        Sleep function with cleanup.
        '''
        try:
            _sleep(delay)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit()


    @timeout(TIMEOUT)
    def check(self, **kw):
        '''
        Check if the network is up.
        '''
        self.sleep(TIMEOUT)
        try:
            socket.gethostbyname(kw.get('remote_server', 'www.google.com'))
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False


    def online(self, **kw):
        '''
        return True is the network is UP.
        '''
        return self.check(**kw) is True


    def offline(self, **kw):
        '''
        return False if the network is DOWN.
        '''
        return self.online(**kw) is False


    def if_online(self, func, *args, **kw):
        if self.online():
            func(*args, **kw)

    def if_offline(self, func, *args, **kw):
        if self.offline():
            func(*args,**kw)


    def mainloop(self):
        '''
        Continuously check if the network is UP or DOWN.
        '''
        while True:
            up = self.check()
            if up:
                print 'Network is up'
            else:
                print 'network is down.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NetworkStatus().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6):

Importing `sleep` as `_sleep` is an awkward work around. It'd be much easier to do a plain `import time`, then in your `sleep` function refer to `time.sleep`. No need for odd aliases and nothing gets overwritten.

This function does nothing:

```
def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
    return
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
    signal.alarm(seconds)
```

It will immediately return, and the following two lines will never be executed.

If `TIMEOUT` can be set then it's not a constant, and it should instead be a class level variable. Place it directly after the class definition, then you can directly assign it easily without needing to resort to the `global` keyword. You also don't need to pass it as an argument to `@timeout`, you can just use `NetworkStatus.timeout` directly there.

```
class NetworkStatus(object):

    timeout = 2
```

In `online` you're returning if `self.online(**kw) is True`, but this is the same as returning `self.online(**kw)` already *is* `True`. And `check` only returns true or false. There's no reason to have two separate functions here at all, just rename the vague `check` function to `is_online` and you're returning a boolean directly from there. Then you also have `offline` which makes little sense. If you're concerned about readability, then `if not network.is_online()` is plenty readable without having a specific function.

Further down you also have `if_online` and `if_offline`... what are these wrappers for? They seem overly generic to achieve one small goal (only run a function if the network is online/offline. It'd make more sense to have these specific to the function, rather than passing the function as an argument. Did you have a lot of functions that needed this construct? It doesn't look like you've used it here.

I'd rename `mainloop` to just `run`, or `run_test`. `mainloop` is a generic name that tells us nothing. Also, no need to store the result in `up`. You can evaluate directly:

```
if self.is_online():
```

Now that I'm here I notice that you never passing any keyword arguments as `kw**`. Indeed you never use them, instead just using string literals:

```
socket.gethostbyname(kw.get('remote_server', 'www.google.com'))
```

This is very bad practice! Those values should be constants or class attributes. You should also remove all the unnecessary `kw**` parameters. Why let the user pass in values that'll never be used for anything?

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems to have a mild sleep disorder.

---

Why does this wrapper exist?

> ```
> def sleep(self,delay):
>     '''
>     Sleep function with cleanup.
>     '''
>     try:
>         _sleep(delay)
>     except KeyboardInterrupt:
>         exit()
> ```

If you had just done `import time`, then you could call `time.sleep(delay)` instead of the weirdly named `_sleep()`.

Why do you catch `KeyboardInterrupt` there?  Why should the program behave differently if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> while it is sleeping, compared to while it is in some other phase of the loop?  To establish a uniform policy for handling keyboard interrupts, just move the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception handler to the main loop.

Once you've mad both of these changes, there is no longer any reason to write your own `sleep()` function at all.  I'd go further and say that `online()`, `offline()`, `if_online()`, and `if_offline()` are all superfluous, since I don't see how they could be useful.  After ripping out those functions, it looks more like a simple function is all you need.

---

The way you call `self.sleep(TIMEOUT)` from `check()` is not right either.

I'd expect `check()` to do just that: perform the test immediately.  Not after some delay.  If you need to throttle the test, then the sleep call belongs in the loop, not the test.

You're using `TIMEOUT` for both the test frequency and the maximum allowable response time.  Why should the they be equal?  I think I would want to perform the test maybe once a minute, and allow five seconds for a response.  If you want to monitor the connection continuously, then it seems that ICMP pings would be more appropriate than DNS lookup tests.